# session verification masterpage (?) asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a blank page with two buttons.

the first button's click code is this:

```
Session["permissionUser"] = "1";
```

and here's the second button code:

```
Session["permissionUser"] = "2";
```

and then i have a hyperlink which redirects to the "main" website.

my objective is to adapt the menu bar which is on the masterpage based on the permission saved in the session. here's part of my code in the masterpage:

```
<body>
<div id="menuBar">
<a href="../Default.aspx">Home</a>
<% if (Session["permissionUser"] == "1"){ %>
<a href="#">PERMISSION 1 LINK</a>
<% } %>
<% if (Session["permissionUser"] == "2"){ %>
<a href="#">PERMISSION 2 LINK</a>
<% } %>
</div>

<div id="content">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="websiteContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</body>
```

the problem is when i run the application, even if i click any of the buttons the menu doesnt adapt at all. it just shows the hyperlink "Home" and not any of the others which were supposed to be shown since the session is either 1 or 2 (depending on which button i clicked)

i cant really see what im doing wrong so if you guys have any suggestions i'd be really grateful

Comment: I would debug and make sure the session variable contains the expected value

Comment: You should consider using [code behind](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303247) and modifying the DOM from there. Separation of concerns and cleaner code.

Comment: i did that after clicking the button i used the Response.Write on the session variable and it contained the value. but when i clicked the hyperlink to the other it didnt adapt at all

Comment: Maybe post more of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very PHPish. That is to say, it's ugly. And unwieldy. Let's put the logic in the code behind. We also need a form so we can have controls that run on the server.

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //you should probably also check to make sure the session has "permissionUser" in it
    if (Session["permissionUser"] == "1")
    {
        Permission1HL.Visible=true;
    }
    else if(Session["permissionUser"] == "2")
    {
        Permission2HL.Visible=true;
    }
}
```

And change your ASPX page to this.

```
<body>
<form runat="server">
<div id="menuBar">
<a href="../Default.aspx">Home</a>
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" id="Permission1HL" Text="Permission 1 Link" Visible="false" />
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" id="Permission2HL" Text="Permission 2 Link" Visible="false" />
</div>

<div id="content">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="websiteContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: it's working but i mean. what was it that was going wrong with my previous code? everything looks fine in my eyes and should work. yeah.. i just started with asp.net c# less than a week ago and before that i was working with php so.. thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

I would actually be more specific in the if statement

```
<% if (Session["permissionUser"].toString() == "1"){ %>
```

with null checks

```
<% if (Session["permissionUser"] != null && Session["permissionUser"].toString() == "1"){ %>
```

Comment: Or i would cast the Session value to be a string. ie (String)Session["permissionUser"]

Comment: Would at least have to add a null check then

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you make a serverside hyperlink control instead, and set the text and navigateurl from codebehind

```
<asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink1" 
              NavigateUrl="http://mydefaulturl.com"
              Text="DefaultText"
              runat="server"/>
```

from code behind:

```
if (Session["permissionUser"] == 1)
{
  hyperlink1.NavigateUrl = "#"
  hyperlink1.Text = "Permission 1 link"
}...
```

This will allow you to better control and debug your values.